# Octave does not recognize MATLAB package syntax

Tags: matlab, syntax, package, octave

I would like to get a package written for MATLAB to run in Octave but have been informed by the package author ( see [github page here](https://github.com/claesenm/optunity/issues/32) ) that Octave doe not recognize the package's MATLAB syntax. Is there any hack I can implement to force Octave to see and be able to use the package?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to do this, but do you have to use the optunity package?  I think there are similar Octave packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to the maintainer of the Optunity package about this problem and he very quickly pushed out an Octave wrapper for the package. Everything seems to be working fine now :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it's okay!